# misplaced token error java in helper methods

Tags: java, class, dictionary, hashmap

I'm writing a class that is the transcript of a student, and i created a helper instance method that will add course, I implemented the transcript class through a HashMap, course name being the key and the grade is its value. When I try testing my class I get an error when using the add course method to add a course name only without the grade i get this error

> Multiple markers at this line
>       - Syntax error on token ""CS200"", delete this token
>       - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

and when I use the same method with the name of the course with a grade i get this error

> Multiple markers at this line
>       - Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
>       - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

I'm pretty sure my code is correct but I dont know where did I go wrong, the code I wrote in here:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Transcript
{
    private Map<String, Double> transcript;
    private String transcriptInString = "";

    public Transcript ()
    {
        transcript = new HashMap<String, Double> (30);
    }

    /* ---------------------------------------------- Helper Methods ---------------------------------------------- */

    public void addCourse (String courseName, double grade)
    {
        transcript.put(courseName, grade);
    }

    public void addCourse (String courseName)
    {
        addCourse(courseName, 0.0);
    }

    public String toString ()
    {
        Set<String> transcriptKeys = transcript.keySet();
        Iterator<String> keyIterator = transcriptKeys.iterator();
        String courseName;

        while (keyIterator.hasNext())
        {
            courseName = keyIterator.next();
            transcriptInString += courseName + "\t" + transcript.get(courseName) + "\n";
        }

        return transcriptInString;
    }
}
```

and this is the driver class I wrote to check my code if it is giving me the correct results

```
public class Driver
{
    Transcript t = new Transcript ();
    t.addCourse("CS200", 100);
}
```

Thanks guys for the help

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `Driver` class:

```
public class Driver
{
    Transcript t = new Transcript ();
    t.addCourse("CS200", 100);
}
```

Your first line is okay - it's declaring a variable. But the second statement is just trying to execute a method - but it's not in the context of a method, constructor, initializer block etc.

You could put it in a constructor:

```
public class Driver
{
    public Driver()
    {
        Transcript t = new Transcript ();
        t.addCourse("CS200", 100);
    }
}
```

or maybe a method:

```
public class Driver
{
    public void test()
    {
        Transcript t = new Transcript ();
        t.addCourse("CS200", 100);
    }
}
```

It's not really clear what `Driver` is meant to do, but it can't contain statements just in the class like that.

Comment: the driver class is just to put a few test cases for my class to check if the results are correct not more, but i still odnt undertsand why it didnt work

Comment: ohh, lol i made a gd mistake here, i didnt write a main method in my driver class, never mind it
and thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

The statement `t.addCourse("CS200", 100);` is not allowed in the declaration part of a class. Move it somewhere else (inside a constructor for example)
So instead of having :

```
public class Driver
{
    Transcript t = new Transcript ();
    t.addCourse("CS200", 100);
}
```

You should have:

```
public class Driver
{
    Transcript t = new Transcript ();
    public Driver(){
        t.addCourse("CS200", 100);
    }
}
```

And if you want to have everything static, you could do the following

```
public class Driver
{
    static Transcript t = new Transcript ();
    static{
        t.addCourse("CS200", 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: why is it not allowed to be declared like this?

Comment: ohh, lol i made a gd mistake here, i didnt write a main method in my driver class, never mind it
and thanks for the help anyway

Comment: I have a question regarding this post, when writing static and then the 2 curly braces, is everything inside it private or not? if not is there a way to make it private?

Comment: @aizen92 When no access modifier is present, any class, field, method or constructor that has no declared access modifier is accessible only by classes in the same package

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the code inside the `Driver` class into a method (perhaps a main method?).

Example:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Transcript t = new Transcript ();
        t.addCourse("CS200", 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: ohh, lol i made a gd mistake here, i didnt write a main method in my driver class, never mind it
and thanks for the help anyway